# Notepad++ Regex rearrange Repeated pattern

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am new to regex, I tried to search here the solution but cannot find yet.
Would you mind kindly help me to rearrange this using regex in notepad++:

```
CEyYBUoAfhL.txt; "CEyYBUoAfhL-MI2.jpg" "CEyYBUoAfhL-MI3.jpg" "CEyYBUoAfhL-MI4.jpg" "CEyYBUoAfhL-MI5.jpg" "CEyYBUoAfhL-MI6.jpg" "CEyYBUoAfhL.jpg"
CEyYBUoAfhL.txt; "CEyYBUoAfhL-MI2.jpg" "CEyYBUoAfhL-MI3.jpg" "CEyYBUoAfhL.jpg"
CAjaBo1AL-9.txt; "CAjaBo1AL-9-MI2.jpg" "CAjaBo1AL-9-MI3.jpg" "CAjaBo1AL-9-MI4.jpg" "CAjaBo1AL-9.jpg"
```

Need:

```
CEyYBUoAfhL.txt; "CEyYBUoAfhL.jpg" "CEyYBUoAfhL-MI2.jpg" "CEyYBUoAfhL-MI3.jpg" "CEyYBUoAfhL-MI4.jpg" "CEyYBUoAfhL-MI5.jpg" "CEyYBUoAfhL-MI6.jpg"
```

Please note :
I need to rearrange last element place as second element after xxxxxxx.txt;

Comment: To be clear, you want to move the last elelement to the second position? Or is there another rule? Please, edit your question and add more test cases.

Comment: Yes, I need last element move to the second position. I already edit my question. Thanks. Hope you will help me to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use:

```
;\K(\s*.*?)(\s*\S+)$
```

And replace with

```
\2\1
```

Make sure to **not** tick the box where a dot would `. matches newline`.

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ouoMeM/3)

---

[image]

Comment: Good job ;) you got my vote

Comment: Thanks. Demo work. 
Thanks @JvdV 

But, after check carefully, its not work as expected on my end. 
Few of the pattern has SPACE at the end . 

Please kindly check [link] (https://regex101.com/r/ouoMeM/5)

Comment: I don't really understand exactly understand you but maybe you need [`;\K(\s*.*?)(\s*\S+)\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/ouoMeM/6) then @AkuAja ?

Comment: @JvdV Thanks. The last one work. You save my time. :) 
 I vote your first answer. 
but it said Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.